# PFsense OpenVPN traffic getting routed through WAN rather than IPsec tunnel

Tags: networking, openvpn, ipsec, pfsense

So I have a PFsense firewall setup with a IPsec tunnel created to access a special webpage housed at another companies website. Internal traffic routes properly through the IPsec tunnel for this website. Connections through OpenVPN though get routed through the regular pfsense WAN port rather than the IPsec tunnel.

Is there anyway to add a route from the OpenVPN network to the IPsec tunnel? In the PFsense routes area the IPsec tunnel isn't a possible gateway so I can't seem to manually create the route.